# How to view computed font size?

Tags: css, firebug, font-size

When you specify font sizes in "em" units, the browser calculates the pixel values [based upon its parents](http://riddle.pl/emcalc/). Is there a way to view the final computed pixel size? Can Firebug do this or is there another tool?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, in Firebug, select "Show Computed Style" on the style tab

Comment: Or, equivalently, the DOM Inspector Computed Style view on the element.

Answer (score 1):

This conversion table between points, pixes, ems and percent isn't 100% accurate, but I've found it to be useful:

http://sureshjain.wordpress.com/2007/07/06/53/

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to make a list with text in different font sizes, and compare them:

```
<ul>
    <li style="font-size:10px;">10px</li>
    <li style="font-size:10.5px;">10px</li>
    <li style="font-size:11px;">10px</li>
</ul>
```

This is not accurate, but I don't think there is another option. Maybe using JavaScript.